# Delphi XE5 center android layout

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

I am developing an android app with Delphi XE5 and I have the `Google Nexus 4` layout. For example, the screen dimensions of a `Samsung Galaxy S4` are different from the Nexus's one.

I have a panel that contains some stuff like buttons, edits and labels. I'd like to center-align this panel, so everytime it is in the middle of the screen.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Drop a TPanel on the form and add your buttons to it. Then set the Align property of the TPanel to alCenter.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd have to use the resize event of the form to set the position.X value of the panel, eg.

```
MyPanel.Position.X := Round((MyForm.Width - MyPanel.Width) / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a *TLayout* component and adjust the *Align* property.

See also [Mobile Tutorial: Using Layout to Adjust Different Form Sizes or Orientations (iOS and Android)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Mobile_Tutorial%3a_Using_Layout_to_Adjust_Different_Form_Sizes_or_Orientations_%28iOS_and_Android%29)